# GooglePlaces API "Response That We Couldn't Understand" Error

Tags: ios, google-places-api

Using the standard autocomplete code with a searchbar:

```
placesClient.autocompleteQuery(searchBar.textField.text!, bounds: nil, filter: filter, callback: {(results, error) -> Void in
        if let error = error {
            print("Autocomplete error \(error)")
            return
        }
        if let results = results {
            for result in results {
                print("Result \(result.attributedFullText) with placeID \(result.placeID)")

                self.predictions.append(result)
            }
        }

        self.placesTableView.reloadData()
    })
```

Has been working for months and tonight it started reporting this error:

Autocomplete error Error Domain=com.google.places.ErrorDomain Code=-2 "The Places API server returned a response that we couldn't understand. If you believe this error represents a bug, please file a report using the instructions on our community and support page (https://developers.google.com/places/support)."

UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=The Places API server returned a response that we couldn't understand. If you believe this error represents a bug, please file a report using the instructions on our community and support page (https://developers.google.com/places/support)., NSUnderlyingError=0x600000444380 {Error Domain=com.google.places.server.ErrorDomain Code=-1 "(null)" UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x600000444350 {Error Domain=com.google.HTTPStatus Code=404 "Not Found" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Not Found}}}}}

Anyone else experiencing this?

Comment: if you call place api then it's working I have called place API in browser but not working with with gmsplacesclient

Comment: I also encountered the same issue with Google Places API on iOS. On Android, it works fine.

Comment: Having the same issue. Must be a service problem

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the service is back up.  I raised a ticket with Google.

They identified the issue and are resolving it.  Mentioned it could take a few hours.

See below:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/64280749
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/64994023

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been filed with Google, Google has identified the bug, and they are currently working on a fix. Issue tracking: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/64280749

See: [why loading places in iOS using google places api causes lookup place id query error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45860451/why-loading-places-in-ios-using-google-places-api-causes-lookup-place-id-query-e)

thank-you: @trishcode