# why loading places in iOS using google places api causes lookup place id query error?

Tags: ios, google-places-api

detailed error log is given below

> lookup place id query error: The operation couldn’t be completed. The
>   Places API server returned a response that we couldn't understand. If
>   you believe this error represents a bug, please file a report using
>   the instructions on our community and support page
>   (https://developers.google.com/places/support). Error: The operation
>   couldn’t be completed. The Places API server returned a response that
>   we couldn't understand. If you believe this error represents a bug,
>   please file a report using the instructions on our community and
>   support page (https://developers.google.com/places/support).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue has been filed with Google, Google has identified the bug, and they are currently working on a fix.  Issue tracking: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/64280749